# Inserting image on datalist using image name from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms, datalist

I have an issue trying to display image in my `DataList` from the database and have access to the database that I'm pulling my images from. But when I run the `WebForm` the image does not appear, what is wrong in my codes?

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="dishID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BorderStyle="Solid" GridLines="Both" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="1259px" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr><td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "FoodPictures/" + Eval("dishImage") %>' />
```

This is how I'm retrieving from the database:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Dish";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    conn.Close();

    DataList1.DataSource = dt;
    DataList1.DataBind();
    conn.Close();

}
```

Comment: What is store in database for image? Image path or image data? How are you retrieving that from the database? Can you share the back-end code too?

Answer (score 0):

I think Your Page do not get image on proper path....
use

```
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "../FoodPictures/" + Eval("dishImage") %>' />
```

Or

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/FoodPictures/" + Eval("dishImage") %>' />
```

Try this..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if `dishImage` is a name like `imagename.jpg` stored in database then try `Convert.ToString(Eval("dishImage"))` like:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<% # "~/FoodPictures/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("dishImage")) %>' runat="server" />
```